# Using a dictionary to count the items in a list

Tags: python, list, count, histogram

Suppose I have a list of items, like:

```
['apple', 'red', 'apple', 'red', 'red', 'pear']
```

I want a dictionary that counts how many times each item appears in the list. So for the list above the result should be:

```
{'apple': 2, 'red': 3, 'pear': 1}
```

How can I do this simply in Python?

---

<sub>If you are only interested in counting instances of a **single** element in a list, see [How do I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191).</sub>

Comment: you can get inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870466/python-histogram-one-liner

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242103/how-to-compute-letter-frequency-in-a-string-using-pythons-built-in-map-and-reduc

Comment: Did any one notice the order of output? Is that irrelevant?

Answer (score 394):

In 2.7 and 3.1, there is the special [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (`dict` subclass) for this purpose.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear'])
Counter({'red': 3, 'apple': 2, 'pear': 1})
```

Comment: The official line, or rather standing joke, is that Guido has a time machine ..

Comment: @Glenn Maynard Counter is just an implementation of a **multiset** which is not an uncommon data structure IMO.  In fact, C++ has an implementation in the STL called `std::multiset` (also `std::tr1::unordered_multiset`) so Guido is not alone in his opinion of its importance.

Comment: @awesomo: No, it's not comparable to std::multiset.  std::multiset allows storing multiple distinct but comparatively equal values, which is what makes it so useful.  (For example, you can compare a list of locations by their temperature, and use a multiset to look up all locations at a specific temperature or temperature range, while getting the fast insertions of a set.)  Counter merely counts repetitions; distinct values are lost.  That's much less useful--it's nothing more than a wrapped dict.  I question calling that a multiset at all.

Comment: @GlennMaynard You're right, I overlooked the additional (extremely useful) features of std::multiset.

Comment: This is the correct Pythonista way of doing it. Efficient. Most of the other solutions listed work, but are not scalable. Exponentially less efficient. Attend MIT OCW "Introduction to Algorithms" to find out why.

Comment: Counting might be a narrow task, but one that is required very often.

Comment: For clarity: to get the output you want you need to cast it to a dict, like dict(Counter(['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear'])).

Answer (score 343):

I like:

```
counts = dict()
for i in items:
  counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1
```

.get allows you to specify a default value if the key does not exist.

Comment: For those new to python. This answer is better in terms of time complexity.

Comment: This answer works even on a list of floating point numbers, where some of the numbers may be '0'

Comment: This answer also does not require any extra imports. +1

Comment: I don't understand what does the +1 part does. Could someone explain?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis get(i,0) will assign 0 if i is not yet in the dict. So it will start with 0 and keep adding 1 to increment the counter

Comment: @JonasPalačionis: It increments the counter for that key, before assigning back to the value for that key.  i.e. it's a histogram aka frequency-count.

Comment: It's true that this solution saves an `import`, and the comment on time complexity may also be valid. In most cases, however, these considerations are less important than readability and elegance, and the accepted `Counter` answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: so far best answer.

Answer (score 75):

Simply use list property count\

```
i = ['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear']
d = {x:i.count(x) for x in i}
print d
```

output :

```
{'pear': 1, 'apple': 2, 'red': 3}
```

Comment: You're applying `count` against the array as many times as there are array items. Your solution is `O(n^2)` where the better trivial solution is `O(n)`. See comments on [riviera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9604768/367865) versus comments on [mmdreg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6582852/367865).

Comment: Maybe you could do `d = {x:i.count(x) for x in set(i)}`

Comment: @XeniaIoannidou: That does `O(n * unique_elements)` work; not much better unless you have many repeats.  And still bad; building a `set()` is basically adding elements to a hash table without a count.  Almost as much work as just adding them to a Dictionary of counts and incrementing the count if already present, and that's just for making the set.  What I described for adding to a Dictionary is already a full solution to the histogram problem, and you're done there without any time spent scanning the original array for each unique element.

Answer (score 64):

```
>>> L = ['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear']
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in L:
...   d[i] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'pear': 1, 'apple': 2, 'red': 3})
```

Comment: @NickT It's more cluttered than itertools.Counter - and I'd be surprised if it was faster...

Comment: By `itertools.Counter` I think @Shadow meant `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 33):

I always thought that for a task that trivial, I wouldn't want to import anything. But i may be wrong, depending on collections.Counter being faster or not.

```
items = "Whats the simpliest way to add the list items to a dictionary "

stats = {}
for i in items:
    if i in stats:
        stats[i] += 1
    else:
        stats[i] = 1

# bonus
for i in sorted(stats, key=stats.get):
    print("%d×'%s'" % (stats[i], i))
```

I think this may be preferable to using count(), because it will only go over the iterable once, whereas count may search the entire thing on every iteration. I used this method to parse many megabytes of statistical data and it always was reasonably fast.

Comment: Your answer deserves more credit for it's simplicity. I was struggling over this for a while, getting bewildered with the silliness of some of the other users suggesting to import new libraries etc.

Comment: you could simplify it with a default value  like this d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + 1

Comment: The simplicity of this answer is so underrated! Sometimes there is no need to import libraries and over-engineer simple tasks.

Answer (score 5):

```
L = ['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear']
d = {}
[d.__setitem__(item,1+d.get(item,0)) for item in L]
print d
```

Gives `{'pear': 1, 'apple': 2, 'red': 3}`

Comment: Please don't abuse list comprehensions for side effects like this. The imperative loop is much clearer, and does not create a useless temporary list of `None`s.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Numpy, the `unique` function can tell you how many times each value appeared by passing `return_counts=True`:

```
>>> data = ['apple', 'red', 'apple', 'red', 'red', 'pear']
>>> np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
(array(['apple', 'pear', 'red'], dtype='<U5'), array([2, 1, 3]))
```

The counts are in the same order as the distinct elements that were found; thus we can use the [usual trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840) to create the desired dictionary ([passing the two elements as separate arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727) to `zip`):

```
>>> dict(zip(*np.unique(data, return_counts=True)))
{'apple': 2, 'pear': 1, 'red': 3}
```

---

If you *specifically* have a large input Numpy array of small integers, you may get better performance from `bincount`:

```
>>> data = np.random.randint(10, size=100)
>>> data
array([1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 8, 7, 4, 4, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2,
       0, 9, 0, 2, 7, 0, 7, 7, 5, 6, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7, 6, 0, 3, 6, 3, 0, 4,
       8, 8, 9, 5, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 5, 0, 1, 1, 9, 5, 4, 9, 5, 2,
       7, 3, 9, 0, 1, 4, 9, 1, 1, 5, 4, 7, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9,
       7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 9, 6, 0])
>>> np.bincount(data)
array([14, 10,  9,  8, 14, 10,  6, 11,  7, 11])
```

The `n`th value in the output array indicates the number of times that `n` appeared, so we can create the dictionary if desired using `enumerate`:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(np.bincount(data)))
{0: 14, 1: 10, 2: 9, 3: 8, 4: 14, 5: 10, 6: 6, 7: 11, 8: 7, 9: 11}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an easy answer m8!

```
def equalizeArray(arr):
    # Counting the frequency of each element in the array
    freq = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i not in freq:
            freq[i] = 1
        else:
            freq[i] += 1
    # Finding the element with the highest frequency
    max_freq = max(freq.values())
    # Calculating the number of deletions required
    for key,value in freq.items():
        if value == max_freq:
            print(key,"been repeated:",value,"times")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First create a list of elements to count

`elements = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 4]`

make an empty dictionary, we also do the same with lists

`>>> counts = {}`

create a for loop that will count for the occurrences of the "key", for each occurrence we add 1

```
for element in elements:
   if element in counts:
   counts[element] +=1
```

check whether we encountered the key before or not if so we add 1, if not we use "else" so the new key is added to the dictionary.

```
>>> else:
>>> counts[element] = 1
```

Now print counts using 'items() so we could create sequence of the key-value pairs

```
for element, count in counts.items():
   print(element, ":", count)
```

here the items() method shows us the key-value pairs, as if we ask: "for element aka in the element load the previous data into 'count' and update it into a sequence of key-value pairs which is what the item() does

CODE WITH NO COMMENTARY:

```
    elements = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 4]
    counts = {}
    for element in elements:
        if element in counts:
            counts[element] += 1
        else:
            counts[element] = 1
    
    for element, count in counts.items():
        print(element, ":", count)
```

```
OUTPUT:
    1:4
    2:3
    3:2
    4:3
    5:1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mylist = [1,2,1,5,1,1,6,'a','a','b']
result = {}
for i in mylist:
    result[i] = mylist.count(i)
print(result)
```

Comment: No, not a good idea. Runtime complexity is O(n^2) which pretty much defeats the point of using the dictionary in the first place. Same problem as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36284223/

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.