# Python - Counter merges elements from list together

Tags: python

I have a list full of Windows API calls:

```
 listOfSequences = 
    ['GetSystemDirectoryA',
     'IsDBCSLeadByte',
     'LocalAlloc',
     'CreateSemaphoreW',
     'CreateSemaphoreA',
     'GlobalAddAtomW',
     'lstrcpynW',
     'LoadLibraryExW',
     'SearchPathW',
     'CreateFileW',
     'CreateFileMappingW',
     'MapViewOfFileEx',
     'GetSystemMetrics',
     'RegisterClipboardFormatW',
     'SystemParametersInfoW',
     'GetDC',
     'GetDeviceCaps',
     'ReleaseDC', ...... and so on .....]
```

Since some of them occurs several times, I wanted to collected their number of occurences. Thus, I used collections.Counter.
But it concatenates some APIs together:

```
lCountedAPIs = Counter(listOfSequences)
```

when I print the **lCountedAPIs** I get the folowing:

```
Counter({'IsRectEmptyLocalAlloc': 2,
         'DdePostAdvise': 3,
         'DispatchMessageWGetModuleFileNameA': 2,
         'FindResourceExW': 50318,
         'ReleaseDCGetModuleFileNameW': 7,
         'DefWindowProcAGetThreadLocale': 1,
         'CoGetCallContext': 40,
         'CoGetTreatAsClassGetCommandLineA': 1,
         'GetForegroundWindowGetSystemDirectoryW': 1,
         'GetModuleHandleWGetSystemTimeAsFileTime': 2,
         'WaitForSingleObjectExIsChild': 1,
         'LoadIconAGetWindowsDirectoryW': 2,
         'GlobalFreeLocalAlloc': 10,
         'GetMapModeCreateSemaphoreW': 1,
         'HeapLock': 11494,                  <---------- A
         'CharNextAGetCurrentProcessId': 11, <---------- B
         'RemovePropWGetStartupInfoA': 1,
         'GetTickCountGetVersionExW': 55,
```

So for ex.: 
**HeapLock** (see A) was not merged with another API
But **CharNextA** was concatenated with **GetCurrentProcessId** (see B)

Can somebody tell me why this happens and how to fix that ?

Thanks in advcance & best regards :)

Comment: It is duplicated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list

Comment: @caot: no, the question isn't about using `Counter`, but about an hypothetic "bug".

Comment: @aminakoy search "In Python 2.7, you can use collections.Counter" in the page. Another duplicated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496518/python-using-a-dictionary-to-count-the-items-in-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your list definition. Python concatenates adjacent string literals, so you must have missed a comma somewhere in the the middle:

```
listOfSequences = [
    'GetSystemDirectoryA',
    'IsDBCSLeadByte',
    'LocalAlloc',
    ...
    'CharNextA'
    #          ^ comma missing here
    'GetCurrentProcessId',
    ...
]
```

This has bitten me several times.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in `Counter` does that. You must necessarily have 11 occurrences of `'CharNextAGetCurrentProcessId'` in `listOfSequences`. You can check this by running `'CharNextAGetCurrentProcessId' in listOfSequences`.

Comment: Indeed, the original list was the problem. Thank you :)