# Converting a python list to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have

```
listOfElements = ["O", "C", "H", "H", "N", "O", "H"]
```

What's the best way to turn this into this dictionary-

`dicOfElements = {"O":2, "C":1, "H":3, "N":1}`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496518/python-using-a-dictionary-to-count-the-items-in-a-list

Comment: collections.Counter

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

listOfElements = ["O", "C", "H", "H", "N", "O", "H"]
c = Counter(listOfElements)
dict(c)
# {'C': 1, 'H': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 2}
```