# AVL tree: practical use of dictionary

Tags: c++, dictionary, avl-tree

I would like to use AVL tree structure as a base under the dictionary.
My class:

```
template <typename keyType, typename dataType>
class AVLTree
{
  class Node
  {
  public:
         keyType key;
         dataType data;
         short int balanceFactor;
         Node * left;
         Node * right;

         Node(const keyType & newKey, const dataType & newData) : key(newKey), data(newData), balanceFactor(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {};
  };
  Node * Root;
***methods
void insert(AVLTree<keyType, dataType>::Node* & subtreeRoot,  const keyType & newKey, const dataType & newData); //insert new element
  void clear(AVLTree<keyType, dataType>::Node* & subtreeRoot); //clear whole tree
  void graph(AVLTree<keyType, dataType>::Node* const & subtreeRoot, int indent) const; //print tree
  void printDes(AVLTree<keyType, dataType>::Node* const & subtreeRoot) const; //print in descending order
  void printAsc(AVLTree<keyType, dataType>::Node* const & subtreeRoot) const; //print in ascending order
...
public:
  void search(const keyType & findKey) const;
...};
```

Let's say I got a sentence:

**I like green grass and green trees.**

When I got rid of punctuation ('.') and I lower all words I get:

**i like green grass and green trees**

I would like to put every word in the structure of AVL tree and print it as ascending list:

**and- 1**

**grass- 1**

**green- 2**

**i -1**

**like- 1**

**trees- 1**

where the second 'parameter' is number of occurrences, i.e. in case of **green** it's 2.

I already did it as a mapping of the singly linked list, but now I want to implement AVL tree and I wonder what should be next steps. I plan to make an outside class COUNTER, with several methods, including this one. My idea:

1. Iterate through the sentence; if word (**key**) doesn't exist (**search** method returns the notification- should be turned into boolean?), add it (**insert** method) to the tree.
2. If it existed already, increment second parameter (in this case, **data**)--- how?
   If it hasn't, add it to the tree with data=1.

So, final question is: is my idea correct? If so, how to increment second parameter of template then? Is iterator a solution to that?

---

EDIT:
Here is my implementation using Singly Linked List, but without using INFO:

```
template <typename key>
class counter {
sequence<key> list;
std::map<string, int> map;

public:
void add_word(key new_word) {
    list.insertEnd(new_word);

    auto iterator = map.find(new_word);
    if (iterator != map.end()) {
        iterator->second++;
    } else {
        map.insert({new_word, 1});
    }
}
```

---

What I wonder it might work:

```
template <typename key, typename info>
class counter {
AVLTree<key, info> dict;
std::map<string, int> map;

public:
void add_word(key new_word) {
    dict.insert(new_word,1);

    auto iterator = map.find(new_word);
    if (iterator != map.end()) {
        iterator->second++;
    } else {
        map.insert({new_word, 1});
    }
}
...}
```

but I guess it won't work like that

Comment: It would be nice if you could make your AVL tree class have the same interface as `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

So given `data` is the value you want to increment, and that it is of some integer type, you can simply do

```
++found_node->data;
```

Is this what you mean with "increment the second parameter of the template?"

Note, that the `search` method in your code sample does not return anything. It should probably return a `Node*` or some iterator to the found node (or `nullptr` / end-iterator).

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could modify `search` to return a `bool` (but it depends on how you'd want to use it). If search returns `false`, you have to call `insert`.

You don't seem to have a clear distinction among the APIs you want to expose to the AVLtree-map user.

> increment second parameter (in this case, data)--- how?

This depends on your use case, but let me suggest a few things. You maintain this count as satellite `data` within your `Node`. In general, a map is implemented as a tree with the nodes (holding the key) pointing to the corresponding value. In your case, you just need to keep track of the count. It is a good idea to store it within the node (as you've done already). I would prefer a generic `insert` function, that just accepts a `key`.

`insert` would traverse the tree, to search (`search` called form within `insert`) if the element was present already. If present, it would just increment the counter associated with the node that holds the key. Else, it would create a new `Node` with `data` set to `1`.

Your `AVLTree` will be instantiated as, `AVLTree<string, int> tree`. When I call `tree.insert("green")` for the first time, I would expect the associated `data` value to be set to `1`. If I call `tree.insert("green")` the next time, it should be set to `2`.

Note that your `map` is missing a crucial API that services, "What is the value/data associated with this key, k?". `tree.get("green")`, should return the count.

A `map` user will not concern themselves with segregating the inputs and preparing the count outside. The `map` has to handle this. Doing `and- 1, grass- 1, green- 2, i -1, like- 1, trees- 1` form outside is probably not what you want.

As Sliepen mentioned in the comments, I'm trying to take this closer to the interfaces a `std::map` exposes.

---

As mentioned before, it's up to you to decide if `find`/`search` will return `bool`/`Node*`. But if you decide to return a `Node*`, a possible implementation would be,

```
Node* foundNode = find(word)
if(!foundNode) 
    insert(word) //this should construct a `new` node with count/data to be 1
else foundNode->data++;
```

[image: AVL tree dictionary]

Comment: class counter {
    AVLTree<key, info> dict;
    std::map<string, int> map;

public:
    void add_word(key new_word) {
        dict.insertN(new_word,1);

        auto iterator = map.find(new_word);
        if (iterator != map.end()) {
            iterator->second++;
        } else {
            map.insert({new_word, 1});
        }
    }
...};

but the time, comparing with LIST usage (list is having only KEY, without INFO parameter), is almost 4 times bigger, while using tree should be smaller ...

Comment: @Marta I'm not entirely sure what you intend to here. Why do you have a `counter` class that has both an `AVLTree` and a `std::map` ? From what I understand you were trying to build a dictionary with an `AVLTree` for `<key, value>` store that maps _words_ to _#_ _of_ _occurrences_. If yes, having a map is redundant. `std::map`s are build on top of Red-Black Trees (faster than AVL). Also, could you please edit the question and paste this (and more) code there ? I would be easy to read.

Comment: @rrjanjik, my intention is to create function (method) outside the class AVLTree, which will print out number of occurrences of different words in text file, but in this case, instead of using simple Singly Linked List used for e.g. searching the word, I am using AVL tree. I modified post a little bit, in case of anything, I will add more, if necessary.

Comment: or maybe posting code with solution using SLL will make it clear what I want to do with AVL tree

Comment: @Marta Just saw your edit. Thanks. I still think the `counter` doesn't need both the `AVLTree` and `std::map`. I'll get back to this in sometime.

Comment: @rrjanjik, you are for sure right. I believe I need to be based on insert and search, but as a boolean value, it should work like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496518/using-a-dictionary-to-count-the-items-in-a-list (but it's in Python, so it got a lot of built-in functions)