# Determine if each item in Series is in another Series exactly 1 time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Pandas/Python but am familiar with excel and what I'm trying to accomplish is essentially a v-lookup.  I have a list of contract numbers that need to be compared to determine if each item in list A is in list B exactly time, if the item in list be has been matched to an item in list A then it cannot be matched again.

```
    coll = []
    coll = pd.DataFrame(coll)
    coll = coll.append([cardpay, achpay])


    audit0 = []
    audit0 = coll["Policy #"]
    audit0 = audit0.dropna()
    audit0 = pd.DataFrame(audit0)
    coll = coll.append([saves])
    coll.sort_values("UserName")
    coll = coll.reset_index(drop=True)

    audit1 = []
    audit1 = coll["PolicyNumber"]
    audit1 = audit1.dropna()
    audit1 = pd.DataFrame(audit1)
```

#### all of the data required is stored and sorted above

#### audit0 & 1 are redundant but make it easier to view for me

#### The count in "PolicyNumber" and "Policy #" do not match which has led to some issues in the

#### attempted solutions below

#### solution below leaves "Payment?" empty when prtined

```
    coll["Payment?"] = np.where((coll["PolicyNumber"].str.contains(str(audit0))), "yes", "no")
```

#### Solution below did not work but read this approach was not ideal along my trials

```
    for i, row in coll["PolicyNumber"]:
        if i == coll.loc[coll["Policy #"]]:
            print(True)
```

###### This gave error because the series are not of the same size(shape)

```
    coll["Payment?"] = coll.merge(coll[["PolicyNumber", "Policy #"]], on=["Policy #"], 
    how="right")
```

Any advice or maybe additional clarity on related posts that may answer my question already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy broadcasting:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Policy #': [1,2,3]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Policy Number': [1, 1, 2, 4, 5]
})

a = df1['Policy #'].to_numpy()[:, None]
b = df2['Policy Number'].to_numpy()
count = (a == b).sum(axis=1)

df1[count == 1]
```

---

[What is numpy broadcasting?](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.05-computation-on-arrays-broadcasting.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I still receive the error for the series not being the same length.  I believe this is user error because of something else i have done to filter the data down and not your suggestion.

Comment: Did you miss the `[:, None]`? numpy broadcasting is designed for working with arrays of different lengths

Comment: That was not the piece I missed originally but I must have messed something else up because re-attempting this solution gave the desired result!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- convert listA to dictionaryA where dictionary keys are elements and values are counts - linear pass through listA. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496518/using-a-dictionary-to-count-the-items-in-a-list) for example)
- convert listB to dictionaryB as above - linear pass through listB.
- now, intersect set(dictionaryA) and set(dictionaryB) - these are common elements. `common_elems = set(dictionaryA) & set(dictionaryB)`
- finally,

```
for elem in common_elems:
    if dictionaryB[elem] == 1: print elem
```