# Cumulative histogram has last point at y=0

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I am creating histogram with

```
pylab.hist(data,weights,histtype='step',normed=False,bins=150,cumulative=True)
```

getting (there are other plots, which are irrelevant now) the violet line

[image: histogram]

Why is the histogram dropping to zero at the end again? Cumulative functions should be in general non-decreasing. Is there a way to work around this, be it bug or feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default behaviour. Think of it as an outline of the histogram as a bar chart. As for a quick workaround, not that I am aware of. A solution would be to calculate the histogram on your own: [python histogram one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870466/python-histogram-one-liner)

Comment: Disappointing, but thanks. I can compute the histogram (the one-lines won't do, those are floats which are binned to ragularly-spaced ranges), I actually do it already, though I always prefer tested pre-cooked functions.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't like OP's nice simple solution, here's an over-complicated one where we construct the plot by hand. Maybe it's useful though if you only have access to the histogram counts and can't use matplotlib's hist function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(5000)
counts, bins = np.histogram(data, bins=20)
cdf = np.cumsum(counts)/np.sum(counts)

plt.plot(
    np.vstack((bins, np.roll(bins, -1))).T.flatten()[:-2],
    np.vstack((cdf, cdf)).T.flatten()
)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Solution (hack):

```py
# histtype=step returns a single patch, open polygon
n,bins,patches=pylab.hist(data, weights, histtype='step', cumulative=True)
# just delete the last point
patches[0].set_xy(patches[0].get_xy()[:-1])
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10690094/2) to the question [cumulative histogram has last point at y=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690094/cumulative-histogram-has-last-point-at-y-0) by the OP [Zer0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761090/eudoxos) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>