# Matplotlib CDF goes back to zero

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

While trying to plot a cumulative distribution function (CDF) using matplotlib's `hist` function, the last point goes back to zero. I read some threads explaining that this is because of the histogram-like format, but couldn't find a solution for my case.

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [7.845419,7.593756,7.706831,7.256211,7.147965]

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.hist(x, cumulative=True, normed=1, histtype='step', bins=100, label=('Label-1'), lw=2)
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

which produces the following image

[image]

As you can see, the stepfunction goes to zero after the last bin of the histogram, which is undesired. How can I change my code so the CDF does not go back to zero?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks for your answer. I added the complete code in the question.

Comment: I see. I edited the question in a shape which makes the problem clear with a [mcve] of the issue. (And I would like to ask you to provide a question in that form next time asking, as it saves everyone a lot of time.)

Comment: See the hack given by OP https://stackoverflow.com/q/10690094/3797285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you always have is to calculate the histogram first and then plot the result the ways you like it, instead of relying on `plt.hist`.

Here you would use `numpy.histogram` to calculate the histogram. Then you can create an array with each point repeated in it, as to obtain a step-like behaviour.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [7.845419,7.593756,7.706831,7.256211,7.147965]

h, edges = np.histogram(x, density=True, bins=100, )
h = np.cumsum(h)/np.cumsum(h).max()

X = edges.repeat(2)[:-1]
y = np.zeros_like(X)
y[1:] = h.repeat(2)

fig, ax=plt.subplots()

ax.plot(X,y,label='Label-1', lw=2)

ax.grid(True)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The question does look easier to understand. Thank you.