# How to get count of item repetition in a list?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter

Hi i have a list in the following format

> tweets= ['RT Find out how AZ is targeting escape pathways to further
>   personalise breastcancer treatment SABCS14', 'Did you know Ontario has
>   a special screening program for women considered high risk for
>   BreastCancer', 'Article Foods That Prevent BreastCancer','PRETTY
>   Infinity Faith Hope Breast Cancer RIBBON SIGN Leather Braided Bracelet
>   breastcancer BreastCancerAwareness']

I have just given a sample of list but it has a total of 8183 elemets. So now if i take 1st item in the list i have to compare that with all the other elements in the list and if 1st item appears anywhere in the list i need the count how many times it got repeated. I tried many ways possible but couldnt achieve desired result. Please help, thanks in advance.

**my code**

```
for x, left in enumerate(tweets1):
   print x,left
   for y, right in enumerate(tweets1):
     print y,right
     common = len(set(left) & set(right))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python histogram one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870466/python-histogram-one-liner)

Comment: @BenjyKessler i have gone through the one you suggested but that didnt help. Hope some one gives me an accurate solution

Comment: Use dictionary to keep count or is `Counter`

Comment: @BenjyKessler Dheerendra Thanks guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a dictionary to count the items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496518/using-a-dictionary-to-count-the-items-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in comments, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do this. The code will translate into something like below:

```
from collections import Counter
tweets = ['RT Find out how AZ is targeting escape pathways to further personalise breastcancer treatment SABCS14',
    'Did you know Ontario has a special screening program for women considered high risk for BreastCancer',
    'Article Foods That Prevent BreastCancer',
    'PRETTY Infinity Faith Hope Breast Cancer RIBBON SIGN Leather Braided Bracelet breastcancer BreastCancerAwareness']

count = Counter(tweets)
for key in Count:
    print key, Count[key]
```

Note that the `Counter` is essentially a `dict`, and so the order of the elements will not be guaranteed.